# Resolving conflict between multiple jQuery files

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple jquery files in my project. I am using facebox using jquery1.4.2 but i need prototype and scriptacolous scripts too. I have used jQuery.noconflict(); in my code but its not working. 
this is the url http://mlep.com/~avalon/wordpress/ideas-and-insights/case-studies/.

Comment: You should consider removing some of the unused script files from the homepage, your resources stack up to nearly 1MB, which is going to take a lifetime on a slower connection. Only use plugins on the pages that require them, you'll provide a much better user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be in this manner of arrangement,

1. load other libraries and other non-jQuery scripts
2. load jQuery library.
3. call jQuery.noConflict.
4. load jQuery plugins
5. other jQuery stuff or codes..

codes like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mlep.com/~avalon/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/facebox/jquery14.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var ang = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mlep.com/~avalon/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/facebox/facebox.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   // other jQuery Codes here...
</script>
```

Comment: And now, instead of `$('stuff').whatever()`, you need to use `ang('stuff').whatever()`. When I use jQuery in no-conflict mode, I usually use `$j`, because it is short and close to the normal jQuery function.

Comment: Judging from the source code a mixture of `jQuery()` & `ang()` references are being used also which could be very confusing. Would recommend using one or the other.

Comment: Thank you I just changed the sequence as per your instructions and it is working fine now.